# background vs background-color CSS

Tags: css

I'm using background and background-color to style the background with a gradient.

If I write only `background` I can see the gradient:

```
background: linear-gradient(35deg, #CCFFFF,#FFCCCC);
```

but if I write `background-color` I can't see it:

```
background-color:linear-gradient(35deg, #CCFFFF,#FFCCCC);
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: a gradient is similar to an image, not a plain color. Best when you are unsure is to check on W3C or https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient

Comment: Hello and welcome to stackoverflow, could you read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and edit your question to improve it, like giving better context and more code to give people a chance to help you. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Because gradient kind of background isn't a color, but an image.

See the example bellow: https://jsfiddle.net/jpavnk71/4/

HTML:

```
<div class="color">background-color:linear-gradient(35deg, #CCFFFF,#FFCCCC);</div>
<div class="wrong">background:linear-gradient(35deg, #CCFFFF,#FFCCCC);</div>
<div class="image">background-image:linear-gradient(35deg, #CCFFFF,#FFCCCC);</div>
```

CSS:

```
div{
  height:100px;
  line-height:100px
}
.wrong{background:linear-gradient(35deg,#CCFFFF,#FFCCCC);}
.color{background-color:linear-gradient(35deg,#CCFFFF,#FFCCCC);}
.image{background-image:linear-gradient(35deg,#FFCCCC,#CCFFFF);}
```

Answer (score 0):

Linear-gradient is handled like an image so you can write:

```
background:linear-gradient(35deg, #CCFFFF,#FFCCCC);
```

OR

```
background-image:linear-gradient(35deg, #CCFFFF,#FFCCCC);
```

Comment: Hello, please elaborate your answer to make it better to understand (you can read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer to help)